# Underscore skip the regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've used following code and regex

```
var regex = new RegExp (/^(?=.*[\w\d]).+/);
if (!regex.test(value)) {
    console.log(' not valid string');
}
```

for following requirements:-

1. It would allow all the special character
2. It must contain at least 1 alphabet or a number
3. **only special character will not work**

Everything is working fine but if **I enter only _(underscore),the validation passes, which shouldn't.**i.e.  not valid string does not print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z\d]).+/
```

Your regex fails because, in regex `\w` stands for a letter or digit or an underscore. Your regex has a lookahead checking whether the following characters follow the pattern zero or more characters followed by a word character (letter/digit/underscore) followed by a digit.